# Auto analyse data (natural language processing)

Tags: java, nlp, analysis, ibm-watson

I am an intern in a hospital maintenance company. I am asked to categorize and analyse the log which records all the problems encountered and raised by users from the helpdesk. Since these incidents (at least 2000-3000) are typed in natural language, is there a way to automate the categorizing process to build a web application which can answer users' questions(NLP?)? (This could be something using IBM Watson or alternative ways).

I am quite blur about how to use Watson to do it (writing code to the services it provide, like Q&A and Relation Extraction). Alternative ideas are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Watson Relationship Extraction to categorize the content automatically -http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/relationship-extraction.html